# I remember taking a lot of pictures for my wedding

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, american-english, passive-voice

This is Anna studying English by myself in Korea.
I've faced some expressions written in one of my English learning books.
Actually there is a controversial issue that most of people think these are wrong because they should be a passive form. As my mother tongue is not English, please help. Thank you in advance.

All means, actually, I like to be taken pictures of in following situation.
Are these wrong? Or can I say it in casual English?

"I remember taking a lot of pictures for my wedding."

"I like to take pictures when I dress up"

Comment: In most cases "take a picture" is understood to mean "operate a camera so as to capture an image".

Comment: "I remember taking a lot of pictures for my wedding" means you actually held the camera and took the pictures. It does not normally mean "I remember having a lot of pictures taken of me for my wedding" where you appear in the photographs. Generally it's the person who holds the camera who takes the photo.

Comment: "I remember having a lot of pictures taken at my wedding." and "I like to take pictures of myself when I dress up." or "I like having pictures taken (of me) when I dress up."

Comment: I'm quite sure using the passive form is correct thanks to the valued comments. So can I consider above sentences I mentioned are not being used even in informal/casual English?

Comment: Both types of expressions are often heard in casual English. Although technically the first should be be "I remember /having taken/ a lot of pictures for my wedding," you could get away with your version almost anywhere these days.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Anna. I too am in Korea (Pohang). I've heard those phrases used when people are not trying to be specific, but you should take Andrew Leach and Hot Licks advice to heart. People will think "you" took the photos in your given sentences.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! :) Now everthing is clear!

Answer (score 1):

The correct form would be, **"I remember having a lot of pictures taken at my wedding."**

And, **"I like having pictures taken of me when I dress up."** (As Cargill commented earlier.)